# C/C++, упакованные структуры и требования выравнивания

Tags: c++, структуры, выравнивание

Я хочу разобраться в следующем вопросе.

Стандарты `C` и `C++` трактуют доступ к невыровненным данным, как неопределенное поведение.

Многие компиляторы имеют расширение, которое позволяет объявлять структуру упакованной. И если упакованной структуре задать выравнивание, равное минимальному, то компилятор будет генерировать код, который позволяет с такой структурой работать безопасно.

Мои вопросы следующие:

1. Должна ли сама упакованная структура быть выровнена?
2. Даже если структура упакована, и компилятор генерирует код доступа к невыровненным полям такой структуры, то остается другая проблема. Согласно Стандарту `C`, неопределенным поведением является запись в указатель адреса, выравнивание которого не соответствует требованиям целевого типа. Компилятор как-нибудь это решает?

Comment: А можно поподробнее и с примерами. И почему Вас только структуры интересуют? А упакованные классы, например, не интересуют? Или речь о `C`, в котором только структуры? Тогда почему в тэгах указан `c++`? И можно ссылку на те части стандартов `С` и `C++`, которые трактуют доступ к невыровненным данным, как UB. И пример как добиться UB - пример структуры с выровненными/невыровненными полями

Comment: @vegorov, вот что говорит Стандарт C (6.3.2.3):
Указатель на объект или неполный тип может быть преобразован в указатель на другой объект или неполный тип. Если результирующий указатель неправильно выровнен для указываемого типа, то поведение не определено.

Comment: @vegorov, примеры с UB из-за невыровненного доступа есть на habr. Например: https://habr.com/ru/post/318456/ В англоязычном информационном пространстве по этой теме написано гораздо больше, почитайте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это все вопросы уровня реализации, поэтому никакого "должно/не должно" тут быть не может. Как сделают в конкретной реализации - так и будет.

1. Если данная платформа запрещает формирование невыровненных указателей на аппаратном уровне, то разрешить *свободное* формирование работоспособных указателей на произвольные невыравненные данные реализация может только путем введения своих "супер-указателей", являющихся относительно "толстой" надстройкой над аппаратной поддержкой адресного доступа, с сопутствующим тяжелым ударом по эффективности. Для С и С++ такая реализация нежизнеспособна (т.е. никому не нужна).
2. Если данная платформа запрещает формирование невыровненных указателей на аппаратном уровне, то реализация может переложить ответственность на пользователя: смотрите сами, на что вы формируете указатель. Попробуете сформировать "плохой" указатель - сами будете виноваты. Так обычно и делается на практике.
3. На платформах, аппаратно запрещающих невыровненный доступ, наличие отдельного требование выравнивания *всей* упакованной структуры может дать компилятору возможность генерировать более эффективный код для доступа к невыровненным полям упакованной структуры.

   Если не накладывать на упакованные структуры требований выравнивания *всей* структуры, то компилятор будет вынужден всегда рассчитывать на наиболее общий случай, т.е. что поля структуры могут располагаться в памяти "как угодно". Это означает в общем случае что доступ к потенциально невыровненным полям должен будет осуществляться побайтно.

   То есть выравнивание всей структуры теоретически имеет смысл, даже если ее поля упакованы (т.е. не выровнены).
4. На платформах, где нет аппаратного запрета на доступ к невыровненным данным, компиляторы обычно вообще не уделяют никакого внимания этому вопросу. За исключением разве что тяжелых/массовых операций работы с памятью, где незначительные run-time усилия для учета выравнивания могут принести существенные выигрыши в производительности.

Comment: А как могут быть запрещено формирование указателей на невыровненные данные? Указатель на char мы сформировать всегда можем, а к нему выравнивание неприменимо.

Comment: @Qwertiy, это скорее гипотетическое, нежели реальное поведение. Впрочем, посмотрите на рассказ о компах с [тегированной памятью](https://itnan.ru/post.php?c=1&p=328542)

Comment: @AnT, если Стандарт говорит, что это неопределенное поведение, значит так оно и есть. На то он и Стандарт.